# Stable PHP CMS for hacking against

Tags: php, content-management-system

I've used Wordpress and Joomla to build a couple of small websites, and done some hacking about to get them running exactly as I want.  But both of these, and probably many other PHP CMSs, are subject to a constant barrage of security fixes.  I don't have to time to test the fixes, make sure my customizations are still working, and roll them out before anyone attacks the site, then do the same thing again a month later - I'll never get anything else done with that kind of overhead.

So my question is:  Is there a (preferably PHP) content management system that somehow successfully avoids the constant barrage of security updates and resulting testing/sysadmin work?  So I can just work on it when I have time, not keep racing to patch the latest attacks?

Bonus points for having a sane plugin model to make it easier to code against.  More bonus points if it provides an easy method to import data from Joomla and/or wordpress.

Thanks

EDIT: As rightly pointed out, avoiding updates entirely is not a sensible goal.  Rather, I want to minimize the pain of updates.  So what I'm really looking for is:

- Easy to adapt and theme in a way that is guaranteed not break during updates
- Simple update process

Answer (score 5, accepted):

there is no cms (no software, for that matter) so secure you never have to update. developers make mistakes, and new exploits appear. so every cms *should be* "subject to a constant barrage of security fixes". if it is not, you should ask yourself about the security policy of the project and the security of your site. see [The Open Security Model, Drupal and ExpressionEngine on Security](http://www.lullabot.com/articles/drupal-and-expressionengine-security-models) for a related read.

so unless you don't care about the security of your site, you are asking the wrong question. i think it should actually be: is there a cms that is customizable *without modifying core files* so that security updates don't break my customizations? or: how can i customize a cms so that security updates don't break my customizations? security updates usually don't break a (even customized) site - unless the customizations are done the wrong way.

my answer to that new question would be [Drupal](http://drupal.org/) (including bonus points).

Comment: This is definitely the right for for Drupal, and CMS Made Simple as close second.

Comment: I think you are quite right - I'm not trying to avoid updates, but rather to minimize the impact/workload.  Drupal may well be the answer. I will update the question to clarify.

Comment: "Is there a cms that is customizable without modifying core files so that security updates don't break my customizations?"  WordPress is really good at this...

Answer (score 2):

The last versions of WordPress (2.7 branch) have auto update for core and plugins making it really easy to upgrade when a fix is available. The api is also awesome - I've done quite a few WordPress based sites and rarely (if at all) needed to hack the core.

As long as you customize through plugins or themes, and use auto update when a new version is available, you shouldn't have any problem at all.

Answer (score 1):

I like [CMS Made Simple](http://www.cmsmadesimple.org/), which is written in PHP.

Answer (score 0):

In term of security, stability & flexible maintenance I suggest Symfony framework 
(see:http://www.symfony-project.org/). It has a lot of plugins, support towards wordpress, joomla and whatever you need. 
See also PHPcake at http://cakephp.org

Comment: yes of course! but I just would like to suggest that
maybe is simpler to choose the right framework instead 
of looking for a good CMS. A good MVC based framework 
has its own CMS inside and maybe is tested, mantained, debugged
by a larger community...

Answer (score 0):

I really like [ExpressionEngine](http://expressionengine.com/), made by EllisLab, its based on their open source framework [CodeIgniter](http://codeigniter.com/), (which I think is one of the best PHP MVC frameworks).

There is a free version of ExpressionEngine for non-commercial use, which is all I've used, but the paid addons + modules look pretty slick.

As for actually really free, [ModX](http://modxcms.com/) is alright, but has a frankly wierd plugin system, that said, Ive built a couple of sites on it, and been happy with the results.

Comment: One of the last updates for CodeIgniter was necessary because of an eval() in the form validator, which could be exploited. Doesn't sound very secure to me.

Comment: Additionally, ExpressionEngine 1.x is not based on CodeIgniter, but on a ten year old pseudo php 4 style object oriented codebase. 2.x will be based on CodeIgniter